# need regex pattern matching 'Mr.G@rr!s0n'

Tags: regex, perl

My string is: **(some text followed by) User 'Mr.G@rr!s0n' is the admin**.
I am using this regex pattern: `/user\s'(.*)'\sis/i`
However, I am getting the output as **Mr.G!s0n**

What exactly do I need to change in my regex pattern?

---

Here is the code snippet:

```
$text1 = "user 'Mr.G@rr!s0n' is the admin";

if($text1 =~ /user\s'(.*)'\sis/i)
{
    print "\n"; 
    print "Password: ".$1;
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: In which language are you printing the output?

Comment: Where do you get the string from?

Comment: I am fetching it from a server. But, for testing purpose, I tried it using a simple variable $text. Still it does not work properly.

Comment: @rad Your regex is working, your code is not. So why are you showing us your regex instead of your code?

Comment: Please refer to the code snippet above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am guessing your code (that you won't show for some reason) is something like this:

```
my $str = "(some text followed by) User 'Mr.G@rr!s0n' is the admin";
if ($str =~ /user\s'(.*)'\sis/i) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

The problem here is that `@rr` is interpolated because you are using a double quoted string. Since you are obviously not using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

..this error is silent. If you had used them, you would have gotten:

```
Possible unintended interpolation of @rr in string at
Global symbol "@rr" requires explicit package name at
```

To fix the problem, single quote your string using either `''` or `q()`:

```
my $str = q#(some text followed by) User 'Mr.G@rr!s0n' is the admin#;
```

As you notice, I used `#` as delimiter for `q()`, because both single quote and parentheses were already in the string.

The other possibility is that you are using your match in some kind of evaluation, but that would be silly. So I am not going to make guesses there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was not aware about q(). And my code is exactly as you guessed! :)

Comment: @rad Well, not exactly.. =P You're welcome. Oh, and in the future, always use strict and warnings and you will have much fewer problems like this.

Comment: Yes, I will make sure that I use it. Is it because of q() that @arr is not being considered as an array variable?

Comment: Yes. Double quoted strings cause variables to be interpolated. Single quoted strings do not.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Perl? If so, the `@rr` part of the substring could be interpolated to an empty string (assuming you have no array named "rr"). Do you need to escape the @ somehow?

Comment: Yes, I am using Perl. How do I escape @ ?

Answer (score 0):

If your regex engine supports positive lookbehinds, you could try something like this:

regex `(?<=User ').*(?=')`

matches `Mr.G@rr!s0n`

in the string `User 'Mr.G@rr!s0n' is the admin`

Comment: This regex is actually matching but I am not getting any output in $1, neither in $2.
I am using:
if($text1 =~ /(?<=password ').*(?=')/i)

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't know you were using Perl. It looks like it's Perl specific so I can't help much here. Good luck!